# Display image from sd card (Android 2.3 vs 4.0.4)

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-sdcard

I'm downloading an Image using this code:

```
// Download AVATAR
                    try {
                        File avatar = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/carl.fri.fer.omegan/avatar.jpg");
                        prefs.edit().putString("loginUser", json.name).commit();
                        prefs.edit().putInt("loginMatter", json.darkmatter).commit();

                        if (!avatar.exists()) {
                            Log.i("AVATAR", "Downloading user avatar...");
                            URL url = new URL("Valid URL");

                            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                            int current = 0;
                            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                                    baf.append((byte) current);
                            }

                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(avatar);
                            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                            fos.close();
                        }
                        else Log.i("AVATAR", "The user avatar already exists!");
                } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("Error downloading avatar: " + e); }
```

And then I try to show this image using this code:

```
File usrAvatar = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/carl.fri.fer.omegan/avatar.jpg");
            if(usrAvatar.exists()) {

                Bitmap avatarBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(usrAvatar.getAbsolutePath());
                userAvatar.setImageBitmap(avatarBmp);
            }
```

The problem appears here:

```
userAvatar.setImageBitmap(avatarBmp);
```

Android 4.0.4: Error type: **NullPointerException**.

Android 2.3.5: Error type: **ImageView not showing image but no error appears**.

1- The `ImageView` userAvatar is right because I can show and image from the drawable folder.

2- The image I want to show is downloaded successfully because using a file manager I can find it on the specified folder and file name.

3- The image is not corrupted because I can open it using any image viewer.

So, which can be the problem? It's driving be crazy!

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advantatge!

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
        ImageView bmImage;
      FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/Pictures/Image.png"); 
            BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream); 
            byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()]; 
            bif.read(byteImage1); 
            textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage1+"\r\n"); 
                        bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage1, 0, byteImage1.length));
            textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage2+"\r\n");
```

Comment: 17179 is the lenght of that image , now i have edited the answer check

Comment: It stills trhowing NullPointerException and the `textView` trhows **[B@4178be30**...

Comment: somewhere you are doing wrong, its working well and fine for me... Leave about textview... ImageView will display the image from the SDCard file like what i have mentioned...  bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage1, 0, byteImage1.length));
this will display the image on the screen

Comment: All the code i'm using to download, store and show the image it's all in my question. I do not understand it... I reteieve de image and it is ok.